# Adobe DTM unload Event-based rules

Tags: tags, adobe-analytics

is it possible to bind an Event-based rule, within Adobe DTM, to an "**unload**" event of the page?
I can't find this event among those available when creating the rule.
If it's not expected, I think I'd switch to a Page-load rule based on a Custom Script.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use custom Code within DTM to achieve the objective as currently it is not a available option within DTM.
Hope this helps!